# Grouping dates using NSFetchedResultsController in numberOfSectionsInTableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an `UITableViewController` that shows a list using `NSFetchedResultsController`.
This is a list of myObject and has a attribute `date`.

I have created a method `- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController` to get all Entries sorted by date.

The result is this:
[image]

After this I have added the `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` so that time + date would be shown in `dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle`.

As shown below, you can see that the dates are printed properly, but the 2 lines with MAR 12, 2014 and the other 2 with MAR 14, 2014 are not grouped together.

[image]

My guess is that I need to change the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method, as it is still looking at the dates + time, and not only to the dates, but I have no idea how.

My code:

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        NSInteger count = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
        return count;
    }
```

One possibility is to add an attribute to my Object like 'sectionIdentifier' to store only dates in it and use that. I would like to know if anyone has another idea how to approach this. Is it possible to get these dates grouped together my adding code to `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`?

Comment: you may want to add a section property based on `NSString` that holds the date in the format you want while keeping the real date stored as `NSDate`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I have tried to add to a NSString, but that doesn't work. If I use NSLOG I get this [_bds fetchedResultsController ]sections] (
    "<_NSDefaultSectionInfo: 0x1097ce5d0>",
    "<_NSDefaultSectionInfo: 0x1097d0230>",
    "<_NSDefaultSectionInfo: 0x1097d0b20>",
    "<_NSDefaultSectionInfo: 0x1097ceca0>",
    "<_NSDefaultSectionInfo: 0x1097cff00>",
    "<_NSDefaultSectionInfo: 0x1097d0010>",
    "<_NSDefaultSectionInfo: 0x1097d0600>",
    "<_NSDefaultSectionInfo: 0x1097d0790>",
    "<_NSDefaultSectionInfo: 0x1097d1770>",
    "<_NSDefaultSectionInfo: 0x1097d1370>"

Comment: Your data model needs to be expanded to have a string...

Comment: What I try to say is that NSString *foo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections] doesn't work, or did you mean something else?

Comment: I mean you need a string in your data model that contains the date exactly as you need it for the sections...

Comment: ok yes, that is what I meant with adding the sectionIdentifier.

Comment: But it seemed redundant to have a attribute with date + one with the date/string in it, that is why I wanted to know if there is another way for it.

Comment: And ofcourse thank you!

Comment: the problem is that dates are stored as offset in seconds to a reference which makes working with them sometimes ahrd. your welcome.

Comment: Yes I've noticed and was hoping that there was an easier solution for it. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A NSFetchedResultsController with date as sectionNameKeyPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418703/a-nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-date-as-sectionnamekeypath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like controlling it with the FRC, and leave the delegate calls to change it if they want different/custom functionality.  I also believe that the FRC should generally be constructed as a class method on the entity being observed.

You can make the formatted string be a full-on attribute of the object, but that seems wasteful.

You could also make it be a true transient attribute.  That may be more proper, but I was using an existing model, and didn't want to change the model.  Since that project, I have just kept with this methodology for any other similar cases.

Anyway, this example is almost taken straight from an existing app.  I had to change some things, so I hope I didn't leave out anything.

Create the fetch request used by your FRC, so that it sorts based on the `date` property of the object.  This allows normal core data fetching on a standard property.

```
+ (NSFetchedResultsController *)
    fetchedResultsController:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest
        fetchRequestWithEntityName:[self entityName]];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor
        sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date"
                    ascending:YES]];
    request.fetchBatchSize = 30;
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;

    NSString *cacheName = [[self entityName]
        stringByAppendingString:@"-all-bydate"];
    return [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
        initWithFetchRequest:request
        managedObjectContext:context
          sectionNameKeyPath:@"dateAsSectionName"
                   cacheName:cacheName];
}
```

Add an instance variable to your subclass... you will manage it yourself...

```
@implementation MyManagedObjectSubclass {
    NSString *dateAsSectionName_;
}
```

Add an accessor method.  We only create the formatter once.  Change it to your own liking.

```
- (NSString*)dateAsSectionName
{
    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, MMM d, h:mm a";
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE MMMM d";
    });

    if (dateAsSectionName_ == nil) {
        NSDate *date = [self primitiveDate];
        dateAsSectionName_ = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    }
    return dateAsSectionName_;
}
```

Clear out our section name when the date changes, so we will re-compute its value the next time the accessor is called.

```
- (void)setDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    if ([[self primitiveDate] isEqualToDate:date]) return;

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"date"];
    [self setPrimitiveDate:date];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"date"];

    dateAsSectionName_ = nil;
}
```

Tell KVO that `dateAsSectionName` depends on `date`.

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingDateAsSectionName
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"date"];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Worked out the answer in Swift 4.2.

There are two steps:

Step 1: create `extension` on your `NSManagedObject` (example uses `Entry` as a managed object), and expose it with `@objc`:

```
extension Entry {
    @objc var isoDate: String { get {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        // insert settings for TimeZone and Calendar here
        return formatter.string(from: Entry.date!)
    }}
}
```

Step 2: Use the property `isoDate` as the value for `sectionNameKeyPath`:

```
let fetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: expenseFetchRequest(),
                                                             managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.mainContext,
                                                             sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Expense.dateISO),
                                                             cacheName: nil)
```

By now, your FRC should be able to put the objects into sections!

Answer (score -2):

Reading both post, adding an attribute seems to be the answer